# FeatureBuild block in build.gradle(:app) error "Could not find FeatureBuild() for arguments [...]"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

I'm using Kotlin to build a time-tracking app. I've begun to add the `FeatureBuild` block at the bottom of my `build.gradle` file but get the following message:

> Could not find method FeatureBuild() for arguments [build_8wqpw23x464wiwqh3u30fcxmx$_run_closure1$_closure7@2f246dd9] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

without the block there are no errors. Any advice?

Here's the full `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.loginpage'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.loginpage"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    FeatureBuild {
        ViewBinding true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
    FeatureBuild {
        ViewBinding true
    }
```

it should be

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```